# Xamarin forms: How to render same entered A entry text in B entry and vise versa

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, textchanged, bindable

How do I render text entered in A entry text in B entry and vise versa?

I'm very new to Xamarin forms development.

ViewModal: Below are Entry field bindable objects, Here each field has its decimal validation.
Requirement : if A entry text changed, B entry text should change based on entered text and vise versa.

Here, I facing problems in handling OnPropertyChanged.

```
    private string _inputValues_PercentTimer;
    public string InputValues_PercentTimer
    {
        get { return _inputValues_PercentTimer; }
        set
        {
            _inputValues_PercentTimer = CalculationActions.DecimalValidation(value, _inputValues_PercentTimer, 1, 0.0, 100.0, "");
            OnPropertyChanged("InputValues_PercentTimer");
        }
    }


    private string _inputValues_AppDepth;
    public string InputValues_AppDepth
    {
        get { return _inputValues_AppDepth; }
        set
        {

            _inputValues_AppDepth = CalculationActions.DecimalValidation(value, _inputValues_AppDepth, 3, 0.000, 100.00, "");
            OnPropertyChanged("InputValues_AppDepth");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm facing issues in handling decimal validation and OnPropertyChanged.

Comment: instead of saying "facing problems", why don't you describe the *specific* problems that you are having?

Comment: Sure Jason.
A entry, B entry texts should change at same time based on entered value in either A or B and vise versa. Please suggest steps to follow and let me know if you require more information

Comment: You have two properties and two entries. How do the two properties interact? It looks like they're independent

Comment: At this point there are independent, but while A entry text is entered, B entry text should change doing some calculations and same vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry the poor english

Use the A entry to bind with your viewmodel and in the B entry, make a cross reference binding (I'm not sure this is the correct term).

[This link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/) is about binding basics, and it may help you.

Here is some XAML piece of code with this:
...

```
<Slider x:Name="sdrMediumBattery" 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    Value="{Binding MediumBattery}"`
    Maximum="100" 
    Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
```

...

```
<Label x:Name="lblMediumBattery" 
    BindingContext="{x:Reference sdrMediumBattery}"
    FontSize="Large" 
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
    WidthRequest="50" 
    Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='{0:#00}'}"/>
```

I'm using the property 'Value' from the 'sdrMediumBattery' view (a slider) and binding to the 'Text' property of the Label. The slider is binding to my viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue, Prevent deadlock between dependent properties. Thanks all for supporting.

```
private string _inputValues_PercentTimer;
public string InputValues_PercentTimer
{
    get { return _inputValues_PercentTimer; }
    set
    {
        if (_inputValues_PercentTimer != value && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            _inputValues_PercentTimer = CalculationActions.DecimalValidation(value, _inputValues_PercentTimer, 1, 0.0, 100.0, "");
            double calRes = 5 + double.Parse(_inputValues_PercentTimer);
            _inputValues_AppDepth = calRes.ToString();
            OnPropertyChanged("InputValues_AppDepth");
            OnPropertyChanged("InputValues_PercentTimer");
        }
    }
}

private string _inputValues_AppDepth;
public string InputValues_AppDepth
{
    get { return _inputValues_AppDepth; }
    set
    {
        if (_inputValues_AppDepth != value && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            _inputValues_AppDepth = CalculationActions.DecimalValidation(value, _inputValues_AppDepth, 3, 0.000, 100.00, "");
            double calRes = 5 + double.Parse(_inputValues_AppDepth);
            _inputValues_PercentTimer = calRes.ToString();
            OnPropertyChanged("InputValues_PercentTimer");
            OnPropertyChanged("InputValues_AppDepth");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a tip: I'd suggest replacing strings like "InputValues_PercentTimer" with things like nameof(InputValues_PercentTimer) to avoid accidentally breaking things with future refactors